# What is precise name of the following AES-128 algorithm?

Tags: java, encryption

I have the following decryption algorithm implemented in Java. Is information "AES128" enough for other people to implement it in other languages or a more accurate definition is required?

```
  // input data
  byte[] secretKey = { ... };
  byte[] encryptedData = { ... };

  // decryption
  SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
  random.setSeed(secretKey);
  KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
  keyGen.init(128, random);
  SecretKey sk = keyGen.generateKey();
  SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(sk.getEncoded(), "AES");
  Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
  IvParameterSpec IV16 = new IvParameterSpec(keySpec.getEncoded());
  cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec, IV16);
  byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encryptedData);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essential properties of that algorithm are:

1. AES
2. 128-bit key
3. CBC blocks
4. PKCS-5 aka PKCS-7

Also the following custom tactics used:

1. custom IV generation from a pass phrase used (bad style)
2. custom key generation from a pass phrase

Changing any point, changes everything: bytes generated and decryption code.

Answer (score 4):

The name of the encryption algorithm itself is AES-128. It's being used in the [cipher block chaining mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cipher_block_chaining#Cipher-block_chaining_.28CBC.29) (this describes how to connect the encryption of multiple sequential blocks), with [PKCS #5 padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_%28cryptography%29#PKCS7) (this describes how to pad messages up to the size of a full block). Other languages might have different techniques for specifying mode and padding.

Answer (score 0):

AES is the algo, and 128bit the key size. I would say it's pretty clear ...